# Minimum Spanning Tree of weighted graph

Tags: prolog

I need to write a predicate that creates a minimum spanning tree of a weighted undirected graph, using [Prim's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm). This is what I have so far:

```
% call the recursive predicate with the list of all nodes and
%    one element (in this case the last one).
mst(T) :- nodes(N), last(N,E), mst(T,N,E).

% The element E is added to the visited list and removed from the toVisit list.
mst(T,N,E) :- append(T,E,S), delete(R,E,L)...
```

Then the `toVisit` list should be sorted according to the distance of the edges connected to any of the nodes in the visited list. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Where is the `toVisit` list referenced? What does a specific representation of your tree look like?

Comment: The toVisit list would be the N argument of mst. The graph is represented by connection(N,M,Cost) :- edge(N, M, Cost), \+(N=M). and connection(N,M,Cost) :- edge(M, N, Cost), \+(N=M).

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all let's try to create a solution to find a spanning tree, not minimum, from wikipedia: "spanning tree `T` of an undirected graph `G` is a subgraph that is a tree which includes all of the vertices of `G`, with minimum possible number of edges" and "A tree is a connected undirected graph with no cycles. It is a spanning tree of a graph `G` if it spans `G` (that is, it includes every vertex of `G`) and is a subgraph of `G` (every edge in the tree belongs to `G`)". In this example, i consider a graph built in this way:

```
graph(ListOfVertices,ListOfEdges)
```

and each element of ListOfEdges is `edge(X,Y,Cost)`.

Let's build a predicate that creates a tree (in this case a fully connected graph). `make_kn_weighted/4` has as input the degree of each node (`Size`), the `MinValue` and `MaxValue` of edges's cost and creates the Graph in `graph(LV,Comb)`.

```
make_kn_weighted(Size,MinValue,MaxValue,graph(LV,Comb)):-
    Size1 is Size+1,
    make_ordered_list(1,Size1,LV),
    find_all_combinations_weighted(LV,MinValue,MaxValue,[],Comb).

make_ordered_list(Max,Max,[]):- !.
make_ordered_list(I,Max,[I|T]):-
    I < Max,
    I1 is I+1,
    make_ordered_list(I1,Max,T).

find_all_combinations_weighted([_],_,_,C,C):- !.
find_all_combinations_weighted([H|T],Min,Max,CT,CO):-
    find_combinations_weighted(H,T,Min,Max,C),
    append(CT,C,C1),
    find_all_combinations_weighted(T,Min,Max,C1,CO).

find_combinations_weighted(_,[],_,_,[]):- !.
find_combinations_weighted(E,[H|T],Min,Max,[edge(E,H,V)|TE]):-
    random(Min,Max,V),
    find_combinations_weighted(E,T,Min,Max,TE).

?- make_kn_weighted(4,2,7,G).
G = graph([1, 2, 3, 4], [edge(1, 2, 6), edge(1, 3, 6), edge(1, 4, 5), edge(2, 3, 4), edge(2, 4, 5), edge(3, 4, 5)]).
```

Then we crate a predicate that generates a spanning tree:

```
spanning_tree(graph([N|T],Edges),graph([N|T],TreeEdges)) :- 
   generate_spanning_tree(T,Edges,TreeEdgesUnsorted),
   sort(TreeEdgesUnsorted,TreeEdges).

generate_spanning_tree([],_,[]).
generate_spanning_tree(Curr,Edges,[Edge|T]) :- 
    select(Edge,Edges,Edges1),
    get_vertices(Edge,X,Y),
    is_connected_to_tree(X,Y,Curr),
    delete(Curr,X,Curr1),
    delete(Curr1,Y,Curr2),
    generate_spanning_tree(Curr2,Edges1,T).

get_vertices(edge(X,Y),X,Y).
get_vertices(edge(X,Y,_),X,Y).

is_connected_to_tree(X,Y,Ns):- 
    memberchk(X,Ns), 
    \+ memberchk(Y,Ns), !.
is_connected_to_tree(X,Y,Ns):- 
    memberchk(Y,Ns), 
    \+ memberchk(X,Ns).
```

So, obviously, both the spanning tree and the graph have the same vertices, and this is why i wrote `graph([N|T],Edges),graph([N|T],TreeEdges)`. To generate the actual tree, firs we select a node from the list, with `select/3` (in `Edges1` we have all the elements from `Edges` without `Edge`. Then with `get_vertices/3` we foud the two vertices connected by an edge. With `is_connected_to_tree/3` we check if the two vertices are not already connected (in the list or remaining verices). Then we delete the two selected edges to the list of unconnected vertices (`Curr`) using two times `delete/3` applied to `Curr`. Last call, the recursive call with parameters updated. Test:

```
?- make_kn(4,G), spanning_tree(G,T).
G = graph([1, 2, 3, 4], [edge(1, 2), edge(1, 3), edge(1, 4), edge(2, 3), edge(2, 4), edge(3, 4)]),
T = graph([1, 2, 3, 4], [edge(1, 2), edge(1, 3), edge(1, 4)]) ;
G = graph([1, 2, 3, 4], [edge(1, 2), edge(1, 3), edge(1, 4), edge(2, 3), edge(2, 4), edge(3, 4)]),
T = graph([1, 2, 3, 4], [edge(1, 2), edge(1, 3), edge(2, 4)])
and so on...
```

Now let's focus to Primm's algorthm: to adapt our predicate to generate the tree with minimum cost, we have, first of all sort the edges considering the cost of each edge, then we can call, as above, `generate_spanning_tree/3`. So, in prolog code:

```
mst_prim(graph([H|T],Edges),graph([H|T],TreeEdges),Cost):-
    predsort(compare_edges_value,Edges,SortedEdges),
    generate_spanning_tree(T,SortedEdges,TreeEdgesUnsorted),
    sort(TreeEdgesUnsorted,TreeEdges),
    sum_cost(TreeEdges,0,Cost).

compare_edges_value(O,edge(X1,Y1,C1),edge(X2,Y2,C2)):-
    compare(O,C1+X1+Y1,C2+X2+Y2).

sum_cost([],C,C).
sum_cost([edge(_,_,C)|T],CT,Tot):-
    CT1 is CT+C,
    sum_cost(T,CT1,Tot).
```

`predsort/3` sorts using `compare_edge/3` to determine the order. `sum_cost/3` simply sums the cost of every selected edge. Query:

```
make_kn_weighted(4,2,7,G), mst_prim(G,T,C).
G = graph([1, 2, 3, 4], [edge(1, 2, 3), edge(1, 3, 6), edge(1, 4, 6), edge(2, 3, 5), edge(2, 4, 2), edge(3, 4, 2)]),
T = graph([1, 2, 3, 4], [edge(1, 2, 3), edge(2, 4, 2), edge(3, 4, 2)]),
C = 7 ;
```

In backtracking, it generates all the spanning trees (if you don't want this behaviour, you can add a cut after calling `generate_spanning_tree/2`).

Comment: my graph is built this way: `graph(ListOfVertices)`. Calculating the final cost is not necessary. Also, the `compare_edges_value` predicate seems to fail.

Comment: The edges are defined separately, like this: `edge(v1,v2,cost)`

Comment: Use `findall/3` to get all the edges in a list (something like `findall(edge(A,B,C),edge(A,B,C),Edges)`), then create a structure `G = graph(ListOfVertices,Edges)` and call `mst_primm(G,MST)`.